# Sprites randomly stop drawing XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, sprite, xna-4.0

I'm making a simple 2 player ship shooter game in XNA.

When I fire while holding down the space key the sprites for the projectiles are drawn, but when I let go of the space key and shoot again the first sprite isn't drawn at all.

But its still in the game and functioning as its meant to, is there a problem with the code or is there any solution for this?

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //Loading and Drawing the background through XNA spriteBatch

    spriteBatch.Begin(0, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
    spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.White);
    //Drawing the spaceship on the screen
    spriteBatch.Draw(spaceship.sprite, spaceship.position, null, Color.White);
    //Drawing the alienship
    spriteBatch.Draw(alienship.sprite2, alienship.position2, null, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
    //Drawing the projectile

    spriteBatch.Begin(0, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
    if (projectile.alive == true)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(projectile.sprite, projectile.position, Color.White);
    }

    //Drawing the 3rd Projectile
    if(projectile3.alive == true)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(projectile3.sprite, projectile3.position, Color.Red);
    }

    //Drawing the 4th Projectile
    if (projectile4.alive == true)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(projectile4.sprite, projectile4.position, Color.Green);
    }

    //Drawing the Special Projectile
    if (projectile2.alive)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(projectile2.sprite, projectile2.position, Color.White);
    }

    spriteBatch.End();
    // TODO: Add your drawing code here

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but I don't have enough rep to comment.

I don't think this is a problem with XNA or any of the code you posted. Rather the problem is most likely in another part of your code. You say the sprite is not drawing, and based the if statements in your example, I would start by checking that all of the projectiles are alive.

To do so, insert breakpoints at each if statement, right click on them, click "condition..." and then enter projectile.isalive == false, and see if the projectile is dead when it shouldn't be. That would be a starting point.